# How to make indeterminateProgressDialog in Anko non cancelable?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

How to make `indeterminateProgressDialog` non cancellable? There is a `isCancelable` property for `alert`, but seems not the case for `indeterminateProgressDialog`, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
indeterminateProgressDialog(R.string.wait_for_loading).apply {
    setCancelable(false)
}
```